# Create a Servlets-only project in NetBeans 8 without all the Java EE stuff?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets, netbeans

How to create a Servlets-3.1-only Tomcat-8-compatible web app project in NetBeans 8?

I do not need all the javax.ejb, javax.faces, javax.transaction, and so on.

I found the `New Project > Maven > Web Application` feature. Unfortunately, that template adds dozens of EE-related classes and frameworks of `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` that (a) I don't need and (b) I fear may cause problems running in a Servlets-only environment like Apache Tomcat.

Comment: if there's some way not to use maven... in eclipse this would be a piece of cake :-(

Comment: When running in Tomcat, that jar shouldn't be deployed. You'll instead be running against the classes that are in Tomcat--so just avoid referencing ones not in the Servlet and JSP specs.

Comment: @nitind Some experimentation led me to suspect just what you stated. When NetBeans produces the .war file, that war file does *not* have the `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar` within it. As you said, Java links to the Servlet-API-related classes stored within Tomcat at runtime rather than compile-time, so I just avoid writing code that refers to the Java EE classes not found in Tomcat. To protect myself against doing that, in NetBeans I can remove that jar from the Dependencies, replacing with `javax.servlet-api`. Please make an Answer from your comment so I can accept it and close this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running in Tomcat, that jar shouldn't be deployed. You'll instead be running against the classes that are in Tomcat--so just avoid referencing ones not in the Servlet and JSP specs. As Basil surmised, this means he can add the servlet API jar itself to the in-NetBeans dependencies rather than the (entirety?) of Java EE.

Comment: Not quite the entirety of [Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html). The NetBeans 8 `New Project > Maven > Web Application` project template uses a single jar, `javaee-web-api-7.0.jar`, which is a subset of Java EE called the [Web Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition#Web_Profile). Tomcat 8 supports a subset of that subset: Servlets + JSP + Unified Expression Language + WebSocket. Thanks for this answer. FYI, the [Apache TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/index.html) project extends Tomcat to support the full *Web Profile*.

Comment: For those curious, here's a PDF of the [Java EE 7 Web Profile Specification](https://java.net/downloads/javaee-spec/WebProfile.pdf). And here's a list with links of [the JSRs for the various technologies in Java EE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/index.html) such as [Java Servlets 3.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=340).